# replace select indexed attributes with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, indexing, replace, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following DOM :

```
<select id="evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_0_logicalOperator">...</select>
<select id="evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_1_logicalOperator">...</select>
```

With JqueryUI Sortable component, i'm sorting these select tags. After sorting, the #1 select is placed before the #0 select.
I would like to re-index these selects accordingly to the new DOM.

Here is my sortable instanciation :

```
// Sortable assertions
$collectionHolder.sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    handle: ".handle",
    helper: "original",
    cursor: "move",
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var elements = $collectionHolder.find("tr");
        var count = elements.length;
        console.log(count);

        $(elements).each(function(index) {
            $(this).data('index', index).attr('data-index', index);

            var pattern = '/_[0-9]+_/g';
            var replacement = '_' + index + '_';

            $(this).find('select').each(function(){
                var before = $(this).attr('id');
                var after = $(this).attr('id').replace(pattern, replacement);
                console.log(before + " " + after);

                $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(pattern, replacement));
                $(this).css('border', '3px solid black');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The replacement doesn't work, `console.log(before + " " + after)` prints the following :

```
evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_1_logicalOperator evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_1_logicalOperator
evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_0_logicalOperator evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_0_logicalOperator
```

and I expect

```
evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_1_logicalOperator evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_0_logicalOperator
evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_0_logicalOperator evo_calculatorbundle_ruletype_assertions_1_logicalOperator
```

Am I doing something wrong with `replace` javascript function ? Or my pattern is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex pattern in javascript is enclosed between slashes, if you wrap it with single quote, it becomes a string.

Use:

```
var pattern = /_[0-9]+_/g;
```